# Setting a conditional color by stat_summary in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

so I'm trying to set a conditional color by a stat summary function in ggplot. I'm creating a bar chart of the means in ggplot, and want to set a conditional color that if the mean value is less than 0, make it red and if it's above 0 make it green.

```
Name      Value
A         10
A         -5
B         15
B         12
C         -2
C         -4

ggplot(data, aes(x=Name, y=Value, group=Name))+
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar")
```

I know i'd need an ifelse statement in there, but I'm not sure what the condition would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much easier if you prepare your data for plot before using `ggplot`, for your case aggregating your data before hand and then using `geom_bar` should be fairly straightforward:

```
dataSum <- aggregate(Value ~ Name, data, FUN = 'mean')
ggplot(dataSum, aes(x = Name, y = Value, fill = (Value > 0))) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge') + 
       scale_fill_manual(labels = c("FALSE" = "Less than zero", "TRUE" = "Above zero"), 
                         values = c('red', 'green')) + 
       theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
# Prepare data: split the data into subsets and compute summary using aggregate
  data <- aggregate(Value ~ Name, data, FUN = 'mean')
# Plot
  g <-  ggplot( data , aes(x=Name, y=Value, group=Name)) + 
  # Add condition for colors aes(fill = Value > 0 )
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar",aes(fill = Value > 0 ))
  g + scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'green'))
```

And the output:

[image]