# R - setting manual color based on conditional value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to assign a color to a ggplot bar graph based on whether the value is above or below 0.5.

Here is reproducible code below and graph without the color assigned.

```
dnow <- data.frame(x=rep(c("protected areas","wildnerness areas","private lands","multi-use lands"), each=25), y=runif(100))

ggplot(dnow,aes(x=x, y=y)) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", position=position_dodge(1)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,geom="errorbar", color="grey40",position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5) + labs(y="Mean Agreement") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank()) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Based on the following stackoverflow question ([Setting a conditional color by stat_summary in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188565/setting-a-conditional-color-by-stat-summary-in-ggplot)) I tried to manually assign colors based on the threshold value of 0.5 using `aes` in the `stat_summary` so that bars with values over 0.5 are green and bars with values under 0.5 are red.

The code and output are below. The graph however does not look correct. It created two bars with a "true" or "false" instead of coloring the single bar based on the threshold value. Not sure how to resolve this.

```
ggplot(dnow,aes(x=x, y=y)) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", aes(fill = y > 0.5), position=position_dodge(1)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,geom="errorbar", color="grey40",position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5) + labs(y="Mean Agreement") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank()) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'green')) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example, no one can run your code without your data

Comment: Just edited to include a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply change your `y` to `..y..` in your `aes`. Although it is probably best to aggregate your data before hand and use `geom_bar` similar to the post you linked. This should work:

```
ggplot(dnow,aes(x=x, y=y)) + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", aes(fill = ..y.. > 0.5), position=position_dodge(1)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,geom="errorbar", color="grey40",position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5) + labs(y="Mean Agreement") + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank()) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'green')) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

`..y..` refers to the computed mean from `fun.y`.

Comment: I had no idea about ..y..! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you use the original values in your data frame for coloring, not the computed summary statistics. By default grouping will happen on every discrete variable: in your case the x and the value > 0.5. So the stat summary function will compute means for 8 groups, and color the bars based on this. I do not know of any way to color directly based on the computed means. However you could precompute the means in each group, and color based on this pre-computed mean: thus you would have one mean for every x.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was afraid of. I tried adding `aes(fill = y > 0.5)` in the `stat_summary` call but to no avail.